# Firebase cloud-function multiple executions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, auth0

I have a firebase (Google) cloud-function as follows

```
// Initialize the Auth0 client
var AuthenticationClient = require('auth0').AuthenticationClient;
var auth0 = new AuthenticationClient({
    domain:       'familybank.auth0.com',
    clientID:     'REDACTED'
});

function getAccountBalance(app) {
    console.log('accessToken: ' + app.getUser().accessToken);
    auth0.getProfile(app.getUser().accessToken, function (err, userInfo) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error getting userProfile from Auth0: ' + err);
        }
        console.log('getAccountBalance userInfo:' + userInfo)

        let accountowner = app.getArgument(PARAM_ACCOUNT_OWNER);

        // query firestore based on user
        var transactions = db.collection('bank').doc(userInfo.email)
                          .db.collection('accounts').doc(accountowner)
                          .collection('transactions');
        var accountbalance = transactions.get()
            .then( snapshot => {
                var workingbalance = 0
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    workingbalance = workingbalance + doc.data().amount;
                });

                app.tell(accountowner + " has a balance of $" + workingbalance)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting transactions', err);
                app.tell('I was unable to retrieve your balance at this time.')
            });
    });
}
actionMap.set(INTENT_ACCOUNT_BALANCE, getAccountBalance);
app.handleRequest(actionMap);
```

When this executes, I see the following logs

[image]

Notice that parts of the function are being executed multiple times, and the second execution is failing. If I close out the `auth0.getProfile` call after logging `userInfo`, then the function works, but obviously doesn't have `userInfo`.

Any idea why parts of this function are executing multiple times and why some calls would fail?

Comment: What is the definition of auth0 and what library are you using? (It looks like auth0 is calling the callback twice, at least from the log fragment you've shown.)

Comment: I added the code that creates the auth0 variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userInfo` is undefined at point (2) because there has been an error (reported on the line right beneath it, which was the previous logged message). Your error block does not leave the function, so it continues to run with an invalid `userInfo` object.

But that doesn't explain why the callback is getting called twice - once with a valid `userInfo` and once with an `err`. The documentation (although not the example) for `AuthenticationClient.getProfile()` indicates that it returns a Promise (or *undefined* - although it doesn't say why it might return *undefined*), so I am wondering if this ends up calling the callback twice.

Since it returns a promise, you can omit the callback function and just handle it with something like this:

```
function getAccountBalance(app) {
    let accountowner = app.getArgument(PARAM_ACCOUNT_OWNER);
    console.log('accessToken: ' + app.getUser().accessToken);
    var accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;
    auth0.getProfile( accessToken )

      .then( userInfo => {
        console.log('getAccountBalance userInfo:' + userInfo)

        // query firestore based on user
        var transactions = db.collection('bank').doc(userInfo.email)
                          .db.collection('accounts').doc(accountowner)
                          .collection('transactions');
        return transactions.get();
      })

      .then( snapshot => {
        var workingbalance = 0
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          workingbalance = workingbalance + doc.data().amount;
        });

        app.tell(accountowner + " has a balance of $" + workingbalance)
      })

      .catch( err => {
        console.error('Error:', err );
        app.tell('I was unable to retrieve your balance at this time.')
      })

    });
}
```

Comment: I ended up with something very similar and it does work. I never discovered the root cause for the double call.